# unable to find gems after switching to rbenv

Tags: ruby, capybara, rbenv

was hoping would be able to help me with an issue I am having since I switched from using rvm to rbenv. Company I work for has started using Boxen to manage the developments environments and this is not compatible with rvm hence the switch.

Anyways my problem is after the switch some of my gems are not found. for example capybara webkit. I have added this to my gem file, ran bundler and all gems are installed as expected. I then did an ebenv rehash to installs shims for the the new gems.

However when I attempt to run my tests I get the error:

```
no such file to load -- capybara-webkit (LoadError)
```

my gem list is as follows:

```
Using mime-types (2.0) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.2) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using xpath (2.0.0) 
Using capybara (2.1.0) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using capybara-webkit (1.0.0) 
Using ffi (1.8.1) 
Using childprocess (0.3.9) 
Using cliver (0.2.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.2.4) 
Using zip (2.0.2) 
Using jar_wrapper (0.1.7) 
Using multi_json (1.7.4) 
Using websocket-driver (0.3.0) 
Using poltergeist (1.4.1) 
Using rspec-core (2.13.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.13.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.13.0) 
Using rspec (2.13.0) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.9) 
Using selenium (0.2.10) 
Using websocket (1.0.7) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.32.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.5)
```

my ruby gem environment is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
 - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 448) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
 - ruby
 - x86_64-darwin-12
 - GEM PATHS:
 - /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
 - /Users/Gerry/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
 - /opt/boxen/rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
  - http://rubygems.org/
```

I believe that the issue may have something to do with my path. I am using zsh and have added the following to my .zshrc as per the instructions at (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

```
# rbenv
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

When I run the command echo $PATH i get the following:

/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims:/Users/Gerry/.rbenv/bin:node_modules/.bin:/opt/boxen/nodenv/shims:/opt/boxen/nodenv/bin:bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims:/opt/boxen/rbenv/bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/plugins    /ruby-build/bin:/opt/boxen/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/Gerry/Sites/EventMobi/Code/ec2-api-tools-1.6.1.3/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin

Anybody got any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've run bundle since switching, right?

Comment: Hi Mike - yeah, I have ran bundle since switching. I have also tried manually installed the gems.

Comment: When you type `ruby --version` what do you see?

Comment: ruby -- version results in: ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

Answer (score 1):

OK, managed to get this working. Not sure what the fix was I just ran `rbenv rehash` a few times and I no longer get the error message. All gems are found as expected.